# Как получить последние сообщения из mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица themes. С этой таблицы нужно получить последние сообщения по section_id. Я использую запрос:

```
SELECT MAX(id_theme) FROM themes GROUP BY section_id;
```

Этот запрос выводит вот что:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["MAX(id_theme)"]=> string(2) "20" } [1]=> array(1) { ["MAX(id_theme)"]=> string(1) "9" } [2]=> array(1) { ["MAX(id_theme)"]=> string(2) "21" } }
```

Он выводит id_theme каждой последней записи. Но мне нужно как то вытащить именно сообщения каждой последней записи по полю section_id. Как это сделать?
Вот таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM themes t1 
JOIN ( SELECT section_id, MAX(id_theme) id_theme
       FROM themes 
       GROUP BY section_id ) t2 USING (section_id, id_theme)
```